# MacBook Pro Touch ID

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

On my Mac-book pro 2019, Touch ID does not hard shut down MacBook Pro.
I have tried multiple options for resetting smc but they don't seem to work.

Comment: When was the last time this worked as expected? When was the last time you were able to force your MacBook Pro to shutdown by holding down Touch ID for six seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
Shut down your Mac.
Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds, then release the button.
Wait a few seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.

This method and another one is [given here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)